# Ngrok download via powershell

Tags: powershell, download, ngrok, invoke-webrequest

how can I downlaod files from ngrok server via powershell using:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://test.ngrok-free.app/test.txt -OutFile F:\test.txt;
```

I can download files manually by entering link in browser, but there is browser warning before I can access to site, and I think there is the problem.